# Rails: How to mock gems, such as fb_graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, mocking, fb-graph

I am using the gem fb_graph. I am new to rails, and am trying to figure out how to mock this gem using rspec.  ( https://github.com/nov/fb_graph )

The code I am attempting to test is:

```
facebook_user = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => access_token['credentials']['token']).fetch
return facebook_user.friends
```

I was thinking something along the following lines:

```
fb_graph = mock(FbGraph)
user = mock(FbGraph::User)
fb_graph.should_receive(:new).should_return(user)
user.should_receive(:fetch).should_return(fb_graph_user)
user.should_receive(:friends)
```

Thanks!

Comment: please find git://gist.github.com/752974.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't mock code from a gem, i.e. ["don't mock types you don't own"](http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html).

However, if you wanted to stub that code, try this:

```
user = stub('fbgraph user', :friends => :foo_or_whatever_you_want)
FbGraph::User.stub_chain(:new,:fetch).and_return(user)
```

If you need to check message expectations, it will require a bit more work to return a mock from `#new` and `#fetch`, in combination with using `#should_receive`.